# Referencing Solver32.dll from Access VBA

Tags: vba, dll, reference, solver

I have an Access database that will export data to a procedurally generated excel template for visibility, more complex calculations/visualization, and most importantly, it allows the user to play with the data more.

One of the basic things this template needs to do is execute a solver routine. Solver doesn't exist in any of the standard reference libs in access (that I know of).  I'm a bit new to this side of things, but I looked around the net and found out where the Solver32.dll was, I pointed the reference at it, it wouldn't take it.  Looked around some more and saw that I may need to register it with regsvr32 since it's not in the system32 directory, I tried that and it didn't work.

This may be due to some admin level access issues I have (work computer....sigh), and I'm trying to get those sorted, but I have a feeling this won't fix it.

Anyways, question time:

1) Do I just need admin rights to register Solver32.dll, and then will my reference work easily?

2) If not, is there another way to reference the solver library?

3) If not, or if I can't get rights to register solver32.dll (possible, my IT department can be stingy), is there a way to open plug solver code into the excel sheet I am using and just have it run there?  Because if there is the code is super simple:

........

```
AddIns("Solver Add-In").Installed = True

solveradd cellref:="$D$6", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"

solveradd cellref:="$D$6", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"

SolverOk SetCell:="$F$6", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$6:$D$6", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve
```

............

Anyways, been searching for a solution to this for a big chunk of the day.  Doesn't help that MS in it's infinite wisdom chose to name this program Access, which really helps when googling (sarcasm).

Edit:  Answering some questions in the comments

Version: Access 2010

Errors: 
When I try to reference the dll from the Access VBA IDE I get this error "Can't add a reference to the specified file"

When I try to run the regsvre.exe I get this error "The module 'C:\ProgramFiles.............\Solver32.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "C:\ProgramFiles.........\Solver32.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again."

Comment: `I tried that and it didn't work.`  I'm assuming this gave an error message of some sort?

Comment: which version of access you are running.

Comment: have you checked the file attributes of the dll? which version of solver do you attempt to connect to? have you tried to set up a reference from within excel? have you tried to copy the solver.dll to some other place in the file system registering the copy? what are the error messages you've got so far ?

Comment: maybe some old/broken reference is hanging around ? cf. [this code](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=38392&p=192507#post192507)

Comment: Version: It's Access 2010

Comment: Errors:  When I try to reference the dll from the Access VBA IDE I get this error "Can't add a reference to the specified file", When I try to run the regsvre.exe I get this error "The module 'C:\ProgramFiles.............\Solver32.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.  Make sure that "C:\ProgramFiles.........\Solver32.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again."   Also, I will try some of the ideas that Collapsar put in. I'll update on how that works.

Comment: naybe there is some conflict with another add-in. see [this post (answer of andyr88 dated August 17, 2012)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/cant-find-dll-entry-point-solv-in-solver32dll/e7a7e063-37e9-425a-bc27-c6c426c56992?msgId=8ecfd5f0-4f9e-4c34-b3fb-5dc034d9e8c5)

Comment: That's possible.   I really wish I had admin access right now so I could just slap the dll into system32.   It might fix it.  I'm so close to the solution at this point that it's setting my teeth on edge.  I've gone ahead and just injected the Solver code into Excel when it loads up.  Now all I need to do is have a line that creates a reference for Solver in excel.   I'm trying to do that from access because the excel project would require a pre-existing reference to be added (nice circular reasoning there), if that makes sense.   WHAT I WOULDN"T GIVE FOR 10 MINUTES WITH ADMIN ACCESS!!!!

Comment: I am now trying to do this from excel by building a module in the excel workbook.  The code is injected fine, but the line "xlVBProj.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\SOLVER\Solver32.dll")"  crashes saying that the dll is not found.  This is driving me nuts.  I talked to our IT guy and (luckily) he was a programmer.  He couldn't figure this out either (the regsvr32 failed for him as well even under admin), but suggested that the solver32.dll may have a dependency on another dll.

Comment: just a wild guess: should the reference be to solver32.xla[m] instead of solver32.dll ?

Comment: Yeah, it was to the .xla file, not the .dll.  Can't reference it in Access but it works in Excel. I feel like little Anakin with his pod-racer and I want to shout "It's working now!". But that would bring me shame because Episode 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a duct tape solution to this.  Depending on the security settings at your location this may or may not work.  I'm not even sure how well this will work at my location, but for now it does.  God knows what will happen when I deploy this

Basically I am injecting a macro into the Excel workbook (from Access) to run Solver, since I can't get the solver32.dll to work natively in Access.  Here's the code

```
Private Sub InjectSolverMacro(ByRef xlbook As Excel.Workbook, ByRef xlapp As Excel.Application)

Dim xlVBProj As VBProject
Dim xlModule As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim sCode As String

xlbook.Worksheets(1).Select

AddIns("Solver Add-In").Installed = True

Set xlVBProj = xlbook.VBProject
xlVBProj.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\SOLVER\Solver.XLAM")

Set xlModule = xlbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)

sCode = "Private sub SolverMacro()" & vbCr _
        & "SolverAdd CellRef:=""$D$6"", Relation:=1, FormulaText:=""1"" " & vbCr _
        & "SolverAdd CellRef:=""$D$6"", Relation:=3, FormulaText:=""0"" " & vbCr _
        & "SolverOk SetCell:=""$F$6"", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=""$B$6:$D$6"", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:=""GRG Nonlinear"" " & vbCr _
        & "SolverSolve" & vbCr _
        & "End Sub"

xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString (sCode)


End Sub
```

At first I had the reference here pointed towards the Solver32.dll.  This did not work.  Then I saw [this thread](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/799561-vba-and-solver-addin-compile-error.html) where someone said you had to point to the Solver.XLA.  God knows why it's like this.   But it works.

A couple other notes.  You will need to reference the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library in Access to do this.   Then, you will need to go to your trust center Macro Settings in Excel (File->Options->Trust center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings) and select "Trust Access to the VBA project object model".  This will allow you to inject the code.   This is also what may not work well when I deploy this.  My company would probably not be super keen on me having all my users disable this safety.

But it works.

Comment: lol, as I was worried my boss won't accept this due to the security over-rides.  Oh well.